# Deleting items from a store does not give the current state in all the routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

According to emberjs documentation, store is a single source of truth.
Deleting items from a store in a specific route should reflect all other routes that talks to store.

For eg:
Route 1: Employee
Route 2: Manager
Store: person

Outcome:
The data is cleared after adding few items and clicking delete all. 
However i am seeing an error Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on  while in state"

Refreshing the browser the error goes away, both ember data and pouch (in memory db) has no items.
why deleting the store does not refresh all the routes that used the store (like getAll in model hook).

Here is the source:
https://github.com/kkganesan/ssmr

Hosted here : http://opposite-theory.surge.sh/

Comment: the routes don't maintain a symbiotic relationship with routes where the store informs a route that a particular model is or isn't valid anymore.  The `all` collection is a special case in that you've been given a reference to a live collection maintained by the store.

Comment: There should be mentioned that `store.findAll('model').then(m => m.forEach(i => i.destroyRecord())` is not save, because the all array will be updated and so the iterator will be wrong. Use `toArray()` to get a stable iterator.